# How to classify all words in a sentence with a context?

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, text-classification

I have the names of the companies (in Russian). The name can contain abbreviations, words with capital letters, words with lowercase letters, and mixed words. The model is trained according to the principle: At the input, the name is given in upper case, at the output - in the "correct" version. For example:

```
ОТДЕЛЕНИЕ СТД РФ (ВТО) - СТД РЕСПУБЛИКИ АДЫГЕЯ -> Отделение СТД РФ (ВТО) - СТД Республики Адыгея

ОБЩЕСТВО С ОГРАНИЧЕННОЙ ОТВЕТСТВЕННОСТЬЮ "СИГМА" -> Общество с ограниченной ответственностью "СИГМА"

"ЭЛЕКТРОПРОФСОЮЗ" РБ ОО - "ВЭП" -> "Электропрофсоюз" РБ ОО - "ВЭП"
```

And then I have to predict sentences that I don't know answers for.

I tried to make a character-based seq2seq model with attention and bidirectional GRU, but with all the hyperparameters I tried, it seems to be underfitted. It generates the beginning of phrases quite well, but at the end it breaks down.

Now I think I need to work with word tokens. But I do not know if there are methods for classifying words from a single text in a context.

I want to tokenize a sentence, and assign a property to each word, what it is: uppercase, lowercase, or with a capital first letter. Also I need to do something with mixed words like "МосГосПаравоз" (or like "McDonald's" which not only starts with a capital letter, but also contains it inside.).

Perhaps you need a completely different approach. I will be happy to accept your help

**UPD.** English interpretation of examples:

```
"SIGMA" LIMITED LIABILITY COMPANY -> "SIGMA" Limited liability company
"SIGMA" LLT -> "SIGMA" LLT
PJSC "GAZPROM"-> PJSC "Gazprom"
STATE BUDGETARY EDUCATIONAL INSTITUTION OF THE CITY OF MOSCOW "LYCEUM NO. 1568" -> State budgetary Educational institution of the city of Moscow "Lyceum No. 1568"
```

Comment: Your English seems very good.  It might help if your examples were also in English.

Comment: @blindguy, OK, I'll try to add an interpretation in English